# weather channel script embed

Tags: ajax, embed, weather

I can't seem to get this weather channel script to run on my homepage.  I initially received this script from TWC:

```
document.write('<scr'+'ipt src="'+document.location.protocol+'//wow.weather.com/weather/wow/module/'+wx_locID+'?config='+wx_config+'&proto='+document.location.protocol+'&target='+wx_targetDiv+'"></scr'+'ipt>');
```

I received a reply to a Google forum post that used jQuery's AJAX getScript method which seems to work in an the online editor JSFiddle.

```
$(function () {
    $.getScript(document.location.protocol + '//wow.weather.com/weather/wow/module/' + wx_locID + '?config=' + wx_config + '&proto=' + document.location.protocol + '&target=' + wx_targetDiv);
});
```

It still does not work on the page and causes the rest of the script to not display either.

```
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
<div id="wx_module_1232">
   <a href="http://www.weather.com/weather/local/98501">Olympia Weather Forecast, WA (98501)</a>
</div>
  </body>
```

It may just be an AJAX import I am missing, as I am new to website building.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be missing the values for variables: `wx_locID`, `wx_config` and `wx_targetDiv`. Did you forget to copy these required variables?

Comment: I have them, defined by TWC.  I left a lot out to focus on, what I think, is the issue.